# Replace dataframe row with dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following row from a dataframe:

```
print(row) =  

a      Nan
b      NaN
c      NaN
d      NaN
e      NaN
```

I have a dict: `dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}` that I want to replace this row with.

I tried a pandas series replace `row = row.replace(dict1, regex=True)`
but it  doesn't work.  How can I do this?

Comment: `row[row.columns[0]].map(lambda x: dict1 [x])` should work.

Comment: Thanks this looks good but I couldn't get this to work. Columns doesn't work but I tried row.keys(), however no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
s = pd.Series(row.index.map(dict1.get), index=row.index)
print (s)
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
e    5
dtype: int64
```

If want replace only index:

```
row.index = row.index.map(dict1.get)
```

Comment: This works beautifully. But it doesn't update my df, not sure how to.... Will accept though!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```
row.update(pd.Series(dict1.values(), index=dict1.keys()))
```

Comment: This works perfectly for the series. The df doesn't update though. Maybe thats for a another question though. Thanks.